# How to pass parameter to controller to get the correct object in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc

I define an object like

```
public class DrivelogBean implements Serializable{

   private String backInfoIdentify;

   private DriVehNum driVehNum;

 public static class TotalMileageIntd implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3268743972404969523L;

       private String totalMileage;

       private String mileageTime;

       public String getTotalMileage () {

           return totalMileage;
       }

       public void setTotalMileage (String totalMileage) {

           this.totalMileage = totalMileage;
       }

       public String getMileageTime () {

           return mileageTime;
       }

       public void setMileageTime (String mileageTime) {

           this.mileageTime = mileageTime;
       }
   }

    }
```

and my controller is like:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="saveDriveLog",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody ResultBean saveDriveLog(DrivelogBean drivelogBean){
        driveLogService.addDriveLog (drivelogBean);
        ResultBean resultBean = new ResultBean();
        resultBean.setRet (1);
        resultBean.setDescripion (UsConstants.DRIVELOG_SAVE);
        return resultBean;
    }
```

I want  request parameters convert to drivelogBean
and my url is like that:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080//manage/drivelog/saveDriveLog/?backInfoIdentify=2&totalMileageIntd["driverNum%22]=1&totalMileageIntd["driveCode"]=2
```

but the page prompt

```
HTTP ERROR: 404 Problem accessing //manage/drivelog/saveDriveLog/error. Reason:Not Found
```

and i change the url like :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080//manage/drivelog/saveDriveLog/?commendWord=2&totalMileageIntd.driverNum=1&totalMileageIntd.driveCode=2
```

but the drivelogBean parameter, the property driverNum of totalMileageIntd  and  the property driveCode of totalMileageIntd is null.

So how can I set the correct url pass parameter to the drivelogBean?

Comment: I don't see any totalMileageIntd property defined...

Comment: i write wrong,i have updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if binding inner static class works in spring.

Your parametter must match a setter
commendWord=2 => you must have setCommendWord on the class DrivelogBean 
totalMileageIntd.driverNum=1 => you must have a setDriverNum() on and a getTotalMileageIntd

The class should look like this (I skipped getter and setter to save space but they must exists)

```
public class DrivelogBean implements Serializable{

    private String backInfoIdentify;

    private DriVehNum driVehNum;

    private TotalMileageIntd totalMileageIntd ;

    public static class TotalMileageIntd implements Serializable{

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -3268743972404969523L;

        private String totalMileage;

        private String mileageTime;

   }
}
```

In this case all the parametter you can use are :

```
backInfoIdentify=XXX
driVehNum=XXX
totalMileageIntd.totalMileage=XXX
totalMileageIntd.mileageTime=XXX
```

nothing else

Comment: true, @user2245634, keep in mind that you'll have to instantiate the property totalMileageIntd inside a default constructor

Comment: but if i create a totalMileageIntd object in DrivelogBean default construtor,when i use the class as a @entity in hibernate,are there some abnormal affection?

Comment: I don't understand exaction what you mean but you can use @Transient, or make a speacial DrivelogBeanForm used only for the form